# Breaking dependencies in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dependencies, solid-principles

When I have several chained functions that take arguments and return values in JS, what is this dependency called and how can I break it?

Example

```
function a (arg1){
  return res1;
}

function b (arg2){
  function a(arg1);
  return res2;
}

function c (arg3){
  function b(arg2);
  return res3;
}

c(arg3);
```

Comment: Please edit the question so that it at least doesn't have syntax errors, and say clearly what pattern you're trying to avoid, and why.

Comment: As far as I can make out, you're just using functions in other functions. That's entirely normal, and not typically something you need to change.

Comment: doesn't that build up dependencies like methodchaining?

Comment: Not even close.. method chaining returns reference to `this` object so you can keep using it easily

Comment: Have to get the difference between method chaining and train wrecks clear ...

Comment: Train wrecks tends to happen when there's no proper encapsulation and you can invoke behaviors on aggregated objects. E.g. `someClass.someOtherObj().doSomething()`. It's a side effect of bad encapsulation. However, all method chains aren't train wrecks IMO. There are two instances where I'd find it acceptable: 1. All method calls are made on the top-level object e.g. `someObj.doThis().doThat();` 2. Fluent APIs e.g. `Request.Get("http://somehost/").connectTimeout(1000).socketTimeout(1000).execute().returnContent().asString();`

Comment: Ok ... I think I get it ! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Marc I do not get how the accepted answer answers your question. Your question is not very clear mostly to the fact that there are syntax errors in your code. It's also not clear why you are concerned about the dependencies: it's just a classic functionnal decomposition of a problem. The only way to avoid it is not to use any functions and inline all your code.

Comment: @planx You are right that I might have been unclear. However your answer and that from Oshada helped me to to understand the issue clearer. Well maybe I read too much theory about SOLID principles although I only startet out with coding. I am writing little functions and try to restrict them to 10 lines max and to obbey the SRP. I was just wondering whether my coding style could be better.

Answer (score 0):

This is called "**Mutual Recursion**".

Mutual recursion refers to two or more functions calling each other. And there's a whole class, a small class, but there's a class of computer science problems which are not practically solvable. They are technically solvable but not practically solvable without the concept of mutual recursion, because it requires tracking separate stacks. So mutual recursion, if you think about it, would be impossible in a language without hoisting because one of the functions would always be declared too late.

JavaScript compilers handled this in specific manner. During the initial pass function and variables will be declared (hoisted) and the by the time JavaScript is executed (final pass) all the functions are available there for execution.

Because of Hoisting nature, this Mutual Recursion is possible in JavaScript.

What do you mean by how can I break it?

Comment: As far as I understood it, the above code is not mutual recursion. There's no two-days dependencies. The functions could all be declared in the order they are used. No?